# Setting different transparency values for different categories in a seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

This question is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60267590/setting-font-sizes-of-a-seaborn-plot/60267667#60267667) I posted here. My code for my seaborn scatterplot looks as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['First PCA dimension'] = [1,2,3,4]
df['Second PCA dimension'] = [0,5,5,7]
df['Third PCA dimension'] = [1,2,6,4]
df['Data points'] = [1,2,3,4]

plt.figure(figsize=(42,30))
plt.title('2-D PCA of my data points',fontsize=32)

colors = ["#FF9926", "#2ACD37","#FF9926", "#FF0800"]
b = sns.scatterplot(x="First PCA dimension", y="Second PCA dimension", hue="Data points", palette=sns.color_palette(colors), data=df, legend="full", alpha=0.3)
sns.set_context("paper", rc={"font.size":48,"axes.titlesize":48,"axes.labelsize":48})

b.set_ylabel('mylabely', size=54)
b.set_xlabel('mylabelx', size=54)
b.set_xticklabels([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], fontsize = 36)

lgnd = plt.legend(fontsize='22')
for handle in lgnd.legendHandles:
    handle.set_sizes([26.0])

plt.show()
```

The *alpha* value of 0.3 sets a transparency value for each point in my scatterplot. However, I would like to have a different transparency value for each data point (based on the category it belongs to) instead. Is this possible by providing a list of alpha values, similar to the way I provide a list of colours in the example above?

Comment: Just use alpha when specifying the color, e.g. `"#FF992644"`.

Comment: I'm trying to use RGBA tuples instead of hex color codes because I find that much more intuitive. However, unfortunately it doesn't work when I provide a list of tuples (e.g colors = [(255/255, 133/255, 10/255, 1),(1, 1, 1, 0),(1, 1, 1, 0),(1, 1, 1, 0)]). The colors are set correctly but the alpha value is being ignored (even after removing the alpha value as parameter of the scatterplot function).

Comment: Seems, there are at least two bugs in seaborn. One is that color_palette truncates alpha, the second is that scatterplot ignores alpha. Maybe not worthwhile tracking down, instead one can use matplotlib directly.

Comment: Is there a simple way to rescue my above code by adding some matplotlib magic? Apart from that: Are you sure that's really a bug? Maybe I'm missing something else.

Comment: The first bug is easy to see, just `print(sns.color_palette([(1,1,1,0)]))` and observe how alpha is missing. With matplotlib it would be `plt.scatter(x="First PCA dimension", y="Second PCA dimension", c="Data points", cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors), data=df)`

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work. I will also open an issue to let the seaborn developers know about the bug. If you want to put your comments in an answer I would happily upvote and accept it.

Comment: So the first bug is [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/64928c910264579bf406d317242de9d56870ca97/seaborn/palettes.py#L244), the second bug is [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/88479dc3a9c5dee00fa697fda73152add0827fc4/seaborn/relational.py#L937)

Comment: Just using matplotlib instead works for scatter, but doesn't work so straightforwardly with `seaborn.swarmplot`, etc., which apply jitter to point positions. It would be great to have a solution which allowed use of seaborn plotting functions themselves.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, this is something you [can't currently do](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1966) with `seaborn`.

However, you can hack it by using key colours for the markers, and find-replacing those colours using `PathCollection.get_facecolor()` and `PathCollection.set_facecolor()` with RGBA colours.

So for example, I needed a `swarmplot` on top of a `violinplot`, with certain classes of points at different opacities. To change greys into transparent blacks (what I needed to do), we can do:

```
seaborn.violinplot(...)
points = seaborn.swarmplot(...)

for c in points.collections:
    if not isinstance(c, PathCollection):
        continue
    fc = c.get_facecolor()
    if fc.shape[1] == 4:
        for i, r in enumerate(fc):
            # change mid-grey to 50% black
            if numpy.array_equiv(r, array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1])):
                fc[i] = array([0, 0, 0, 0.5])
            # change white to transparent
            elif numpy.array_equiv(r, array([1, 1, 1, 1])):
                fc[i] = array([0, 0, 0, 0])
        c.set_facecolor(fc)
```

Very awful, but it got me what I needed for a one-shot graphic.